# Net Core Razor DisplayFor invoke with Reflection

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a classic MVC Index page with its classic loop over an `IEnumerable<myclass>` Model

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</td>
      <!-- .... -->
   </tr>
}
```

In a ViewBag I get a `List<string>` object containing the names of the attributes of `myclass`to actually display a column for.

The idea is to put an inner foreach loop, looping over the list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
      @foreach(string c in ViewBag.columns)
      {
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(???)</td>
      }
   </tr>
}
```

The question is, how to replace the parameter in the DisplayFor, as it is a lambda expression.
My first Idea was using reflection

```
      @foreach(string c in ViewBag.columns)
      {
          var n = item.GetType().GetProperty(c).GetType();
          ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(IEnumerable<myclass>, "modelItem");
          ParameterExpression p2 = Expression.Parameter(item.GetType().GetProperty(c).GetType(), "item."+c);
          Expression<Func<IEnumerable<myclass>, dynamic>> exResult = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<myclass>, dynamic>>(p1, p2);
          <td>@Html.DisplayFor(exresult)</td>
      }
```

but this fails as `IEnumerable<myclass>` can not be used as a Type (for whatever reasons)

I tried `@Html.Display(c, item)`with no luck either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you may explain what kind of data stored in `ViewBag` and what kind of appearance  you wanna show in the view....

Comment: `ViewBag.columns`is a list of strings (as can be seen in the ForEach and described above) The Model is an `IEnumerable<myclass>`, as described.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if you need something like below?

```
        <tr>
            @foreach (var c in (ViewBag.Columns))
            {
            <td>item.@(c)</td>
            }
        </tr>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, as this just displays the content of `item.whatever`. I actually need the HTML code, `HTML.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.whatever)` would generate based on the Attributes of `item.whatever`